# Terminate function before calling again?

Tags: java, recursion, exception, stack, stack-overflow

So I have been working on a program in Java. I have a function that runs some code, and when the code throws an exception I want to call it again. Like this:

```
public void x (String str) {
  try {
    // Initialize
  } catch (SomeException e) {
    System.out.println("Initializing again...");
  }
  try {
    // Do stuffz
  } catch (SomeOtherException e) {
    System.out.println("Trying again...");
    x(str);
  }
}
```

This works, but it will throw a stack overflow error if it throws the exception too many times. How can I stop the stack overflow error?

Comment: Unless you provide some self-healing code asking the function to recursively perform the same task under the same condition will lead to this stack overflow. In general exceptions are meant to notify the _caller_ that the function could not perform its task. Make your `x`  `throw SomeOtherException` and do not catch it in `x`.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? If the initialization (which you show just by a comment) causes an exception, you should not call it again in the catch block. It will just be thrown again and again...

Comment: @deHaar I rolled back your edit because the initialization may or may not fail based on other values. I am dong something involving sockets.

Comment: @PaulMattick no problem... Consider providing the real `Exception`s you are catching and maybe some init code next time. It might be useful for the reader and might also raise ideas about how to handle the problem. Oh, you did not really roll back the entire edit, the second try-catch was inside the first catch! Now it's not anymore...

Comment: @PaulMattick The code you provided is too abstract to give you a clear answer. Your comment that you are trying to connect to a socket makes a while loop with a back-off strategy the logical choice. If it is a server socket you are opening, just throw the `IOException`.

Comment: @deHaar It is true, I had to add another }. Otherwise, I rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a wrapper function, i.e. this:

```
public void wrapper (String str) {
  while (true) {
    try {
      x(str);
    } catch (SomeException e1) {
      System.out.println("Initializing again...");
      continue;
    } catch (SomeOtherException e2) {
      System.out.println("Trying again...");
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this *might* work. I'll try it in my code.

Comment: After slight modification, it does. Thank you very much for understanding my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop instead of recursion:

```
public void x(String str){
    for(;;){ // equal to while(true)
        try {
            // Initialize
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            System.out.println("Initializing again...");
            continue; // returning the loop
        }
        try {
            // Do stuffz
            break; // break out of loop if finished
        } catch (SomeOtherException e) {
            System.out.println("Trying again...");
        }
    }
}
```

And just break out of that loop once your finished, else it will just loop and loop and loop until your computer dies, the sun explodes or the universe freezes

Comment: Thanks, but you wrote an answer to incorrect code :( @deHaar mistakenly made a wrong edit.

Comment: @PaulMattick see the edit, does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow happens because you actually don't change anything in parameters that could affect the function to return other result. That means any time you start such a function for parameters which cause the exception it will cause same exception in the inner call.
When you are using recursion you should always take care about exit condition.
If there's no other good reason, in this case recursion is not a good solution.
You should use a loop or add some condition to exit from recursion, it can be number of attempts in your case.

```
public void x (String str, int attempts) {
if (attempts > 100)
   return;
try {
    // Initialize
} catch (SomeException e) {
    System.out.println("Initializing again...");
    try {
        // Do stuffz
    } catch (SomeOtherException e) {
        System.out.println("Trying again...");
        x(str,attempts+1);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in a infinite recursion if the code go to the second catch. Even if you do stuff to avoid it the risk is very high. I will suggest to make only a second attempt and no more. No one wants a infinte loop of try and catchs.

Comment: Nope. I am working with sockets. I want to be ready when a client connects, do some stuff, and wait for another client.